# Should I always validate the presence of a required attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

With an Active Record model should there be a presence validation on literally every field that is required? Or is that overkill?

Comment: Overkill. Its all really depends on how your system work. E.g user's sign up you might require username but have options to add user's bio after sign up.

Comment: I disagree.  I think if it is indeed required then you should validate it.

Comment: Wow, straight down the middle on this one! @mrvncaragay are there not problems that can arise when you don't validate attributes?